# What does the ftp status "200 A L'HUILE" mean?

Tags: ftp

Sometimes I get the following status message when using ftp:

`200 A L'HUILE`

for example like this:

`TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ALLO 7134
200 A L'HUILE
REST 0`

`l'huile` seems to be french for "the oil", needless to say I am quite baffled. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***200 A L'HUILE***  is humorous version of "**200 OK**" message return in response of [**ALLO**CATE](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/4_FileTransfer.html) command by your FTP Server.

In technical terms of FTP, it does have any other significance.

Answer (score 3):

There is an expression in French:

```
tout baigne dans l'huile
```

literally *"everything is bathed in oil"* which [translates roughly](http://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/tout+baigne+dans+l%27huile.html) to:

```
everything hunky-dory
```

Other than that, maybe try on [French Stack Exchange](https://french.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

The "200" is just the status/error code number--you shouldn't be too
concerned with it.  Usually, status codes in the 100-300 range are just
informative as in "You asked me to perform this command so that's what
I've done and here's the result" sort of thing while status codes in the
400 range are temporary errors (e.g., FTP service temporarily
down/unreachable) and status codes in the 500 range are permanent errors
(e.g.  You're asking FTP to do something that FTP can't do such as
perform a command that isn't an FTP command). The "TYPE is now 8-bit
binary" message tells you that it's a state the FTP service is in:
i.e., It's ready to accept a data stream that is binary (as opposed to
human-readable ASCII).

As such, the 425 code is the one of interest:  It tells you that a
data connection can't be opened and you've got something blocking your
attempt to upload even though you've been successfully authenticated.
It could be that the system administrator at the other end is blocking
you from writing to that specific file location for whatever reason
(maybe you're supposed to be in a different directory/folder when you
upload stuff).